# Texstudio stopped jumping

Tags: texstudio

Somehow a twofold error appeared, just now while typing on my TeX document. In one of the files I include in my overall file, I'm not able to use `ctrl+left-click` anymore to jump from the pdf viewer to the appropriate position in the TeX file. Furthermore when compiling the document it does not jump to the appropriate position nor it adjusts the region in the pdf viewer to the part I'm just editing. I already tried to reinstall Texstudio to the newest version. Any help greatly appreciated!

---

edit: I just realized that also the folder holding the files crashes after compiling the document...

Comment: Somehow creating a new folder, copying all files to the new folder solved the problem :-/

Comment: So it's likely an OS problem, not TeX related at all. I am voting to close. (But I am happy that you figured it out!)